# Memory leak in CreateJS

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, createjs, tweenjs

I created a browser game with CreateJS.
The problem I encountered is that when the game is open, it starts to eat more and more memory as time goes on.
It does that even when I do nothing in the game - when nothing new is being drawn to the stage. I took snapshots in Chrome of the memory usage, and it jumps from 14mb to 90mb in about 10 minutes of the game simply being open.

When I run the following line in the console:

```
createjs.Ticker.paused=true
```

The memory leak stops. So my question is, why does the createjs Ticker (which calls the stage's update method) causes an increasing amount of memory to be used each time it runs?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing, it will be hard to figure out what is going on. If you stop the ticker, then your game logic that runs on tick will stop, so of course it stops piling up memory. This symptom often happens when you are doing something on tick that is not cleaned up. For example, drawing new graphics onto a shape each tick without clearing it, which requires each frame to render the last frames graphics, which adds up really quick.